# Why does a new restriction suddenly appear when finding this potential function using antiderivatives?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, vector-analysis

I have 3 questions regarding the solution to the following problem:

> Let $$\vec{F} = M \hat i + N \, \hat j=\big(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\big)^n (x \, \hat i + y \, \hat j)$$Whenever possible, find a potential function $f$ such that $\vec{F}=\nabla f$.

Let's start with the "whenever possible": $\vec{F}=\nabla f \implies \text{curl} \, \vec F = 0 \iff N_y-M_x = 0$. So $$n x y (x^2 + y^2)^{n/2 - 1} - n x y (x^2 + y^2)^{n/2 - 1}=0$$

But the LHS is undefined for $(x,y,n)=(0,0,\{0,2\})$, so a potential function is guaranteed to exist for $n\neq 0,2.$ **Question 1: Is this reasoning correct? Or is the LHS $k-k=0$ with no holes?**

Now to find $f$, the potential function. $f=\int M \, \mathrm dx$ (plus a $g(y)$ term):

$$f(x,y)=\int x(x^2+y^2)^{n/2} \, \mathrm dx = \int \frac 12 u^{n/2} \, \mathrm du = \frac{(x^2 + y^2)^{n/2 + 1}}{n + 2} + g(y)$$
And $$ f_y = N$$ $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \bigg [ \frac{(x^2 + y^2)^{n/2 + 1}}{n + 2} + g(y) \bigg] = y(x^2+y^2)^{n/2}$$ $$y(x^2+y^2)^{n/2} + g'(y) = y(x^2+y^2)^{n/2}$$ $$\implies g'(x)=0$$ Hence $$f(x,y)=\frac{(x^2 + y^2)^{n/2 + 1}}{n + 2}$$

**Question 2: Was there an obvious way to see that $g'(x) = 0$ without integrating $M$ and then comparing?**

**Question 3: Looking at $f$ again, we see that we have the new restriction $n \neq -2$. How do we reconcile this new restriction with the ones we found at the beginning? Where did this new restriction come from?**

Comment: In short, $n\ne-2$ isn’t a new restriction. Double-check your first steps. When $n=0$, $\vec F=x\hat i+y\hat j$ with curl identically zero. When $n=2$, the curl of $\vec F$ is also defined and vanishes everywhere. On the other hand, for $n\lt0$ the domain of $\vec F$ is no longer simply-connected, so $\operatorname{curl}{\vec F}=0$ is not sufficient to ensure that the vector field is exact.

Comment: @amd How do I know when I'm allowed to simplify? For $n=0$, I see that the square root term becomes $1$ if I treat $x,y$ as constants. But surely $0^0 \cdot k$ when $x=y=0$ also is an indeterminate form? And surely the same could be said about $\text{curl} \, \vec F = 0 \cdot 0 \cdot 0 \cdot 0^0$ when $(x,y,n) = (0,0,2)$ by the same reasoning? When can I say a term vanishes and when do I have to be careful? Furthermore, are you saying that $n>0$ as opposed to just $n\neq -2$?

Comment: A fair question that exposes an ambiguity in the definition of this family of vector fields that you were given: their domain is unspecified. It’s common practice, however, to “patch over” removable discontinuities, i.e., treat the $n=0$ case as $x\,\hat i+y\,\hat j$ instead of $$\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^0\left(x\,\hat i+y\,\hat j\right)$. If you’re uncomfortable with that, make any additional assumptions in your work explicit.